# Unable to show depth cloud with compressed RGB

Tags: ros, rviz, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm having some trouble showing a depth cloud using `/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed` as the colour topic. It just doesn't show in rviz:

[image: image description]

However, `rostopic list` shows the following:

```
/camera/depth_registered/camera_info
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw
/camera/rgb/camera_info
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed
/clicked_point
/clock
/initialpose
/move_base_simple/goal
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf_static
```

Does anyone how to carry this out? Here's the [rosbag](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rnB0YuvFsbG2iKmz8C2J6egpxWhAh1Gs/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333064/unable-to-show-depth-cloud-with-compressed-rgb/) by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2019-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot use the `/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed` (with `sensor_msgs/CompressedImage`) topic there since in the plugin the color image topic requires `sensor_msgs/Image` . You will need to decompress the images and republish them. For example, try using `image_transport` as suggested in this [answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/35183/compressed-image-to-image/):

```
rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=/camera/rgb/image_raw raw out:=/camera/rgb/image_raw
```

or if you have a launch file just add this:

```
<node name="republish" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" output="screen" args="compressed in:=/camera/rgb/image_raw raw out:=/camera/rgb/image_raw" />
```

If you are wondering why the `in:topic_name` and `out:topic_name` are the same, it appears that image transport adds `/compressed` to the `in:topic_name`
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure if directly subscribing to a compressed image topic and displaying it in rviz is possible. You can use image transport to decompress and then visualize the raw image using

```
rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed out:=/camera/rgb/image_raw
```

Also if you just want to view the image you can use image_view like

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw _image_transport:=compressed
```

EDIT:

```
rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=/camera/rgb/image_raw out:=/camera/rgb/image_raw
```

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2019-09-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-09-16**:
In this case, the `image_transport` will throw the following warning:

```
[ WARN] [1568628376.366592207]: [image_transport] It looks like you are trying to subscribe directly to a transport-specific image topic '/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed', in which case you will likely get a connection error. Try subscribing to the base topic '/camera/rgb/image_raw' instead with parameter ~image_transport set to 'compressed' (on the command line, _image_transport:=compressed). See http://ros.org/wiki/image_transport for details.
```

It looks like `image_transport` is adding `/compressed` automatically to the input topic. The answer bellow addresses this issue

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-09-16**:
yes, I removed it from image_view but forgot to remove it from republish node, thanks for correction.